# ASPX Page Not Displaying When Using Service Worker

Tags: javascript, asp.net, routes, service-worker, friendly-url

I am working on an ASP.NET 4.6 WebForms project, using friendly URLs and trying to implement a service worker. I am intending to cache 3 pages (along with some js and css files): Default, Contact and About. My cache storage contains the web pages with and without friendly URLs for the About and Contact pages, but not the default page.

[image]

If I navigate to /About.aspx, I get "This site can’t be reached" and the console shows the message

> "The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:50831/About.aspx" resulted in a
>   network error response: a redirected response was used for a request
>   whose redirect mode is not 'follow'"

However, if I navigate to /About, it works fine.

Also, if I comment out the auto redirect for friendly URLs, it works fine.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
  // settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
     routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);    
 }
```

My question is what is happening, and how can I get the service worker to work for web pages using friendly URLs and not using friendly URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons the redirection in the response the SW receives is not honoured. This is what the error message tells you; "I was not aware that I should follow any redirects, and now that I got a response with a redirect, I'll just dump it."

Check out [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434470/only-in-chrome-service-worker-a-redirected-response-was-used-for-a-reque) for a way to fix your issue.