# Cache Amazon S3 files in Service Worker for Offline usage

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I'm using a service worker to allow offline access to my page. I am using workbox, but I think the issue is applicable to service workers in general.

The workflow for a user is that he clicks on a button to download data for offline usage. This includes a number of files, that may or may not be stored on Amazon S3.

E.g., one could imagine that the code when the user clicks the button is:

```
function cacheFilesForOfflineUse(files) {
    files.forEach(file => fetch(file));
}
```

Then, in serviceWorker.js, something like:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    ({event}) => /* ... omitted ... */,
    new workbox.strategies.CacheFirst({cacheName: 'myFilesCache'})
);
```

is responsible for intercepting the fetch and storing them in the cache. This is of course simplified.

This mostly works, but for one specific case: **if the file is behind a 302 Redirect** (which is the case when the file is stored on S3), and I try to **download** the file (by setting document.location), I get this error in the console:

> ... a redirected response was used for a request whose redirect mode
>   is not "follow"

And an error page is displayed.

There is a suggestion in [Only in Chrome (Service Worker): '... a redirected response was used for a request whose redirect mode is not "follow" '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45434470/only-in-chrome-service-worker-a-redirected-response-was-used-for-a-reque) to store a copy of the response when you get a redirected response, so I tried using this techique as workbox plugin (cleanResponse is as in the linked post):

```
{
    cacheWillUpdate: async ({request, response, event}) => {
        if (response.redirected && response.ok) {
            // Sanitize redirects
            for (const key of response.headers.keys()) {
                console.log(key, response.headers.get(key));
            }
            return cleanResponse(response);
        }
        return response;
    },
}
```

Which almost works, but has one big caveat: it does not clone all response headers. The only logged / copied headers are:

> content-type image/png
>   last-modified Tue, 18 Jun 2019 12:57:10 GMT

Which critically misses the Content-Disposition: attachment header, which is required for the browser to treat this as a download.

Is there any way around this, or have I run into some security limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround for my case. Maybe it will be helpful to someone else in the future.

The solution is to avoid using navigation to download the file. So I replaced:

```
function downloadFile(fileUrl) {
    document.location.assign(fileUrl);
}
```

with

```
function downloadFile(fileUrl, filename) {
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        response.blob().then(function (blob) {
            downloadFile(blob, filename, response.headers.get('content-type'));
        });
    });
}
```

Where downloadFile is this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/downloadjs.

It appears to work okay. But if there is a cleaner answer I'd happily give away the check mark to that.